# Both of my headlight are not working

Tags: honda, headlight, jazz

My car is Honda Jazz 2057 Reg.

The high beam for both side are working fine. Only the normal beam on both side are not working. The normal beam and the high beam are from the same lamp.

I have checked the lamp on one side is working. So what might be the possible problem that the lamp on both sides are not working? The fuses for right and left side are OK.

Appreciate any guess. Problem with the switch arm or relay, if any?

Comment: >I have checked the lamp on one side is working.
You want to say that the bulb is working in another vehicle?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The lamps have been changed and the problem is still there. All fuses are in order.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like both low beams are out. While both going out at the same time is not common, I'd suggest you might not have noticed one of them having been out for a time, then the second one went out, leaving you without any low beams.